# Общение с 3G-модемом через КОМ-порт

Tags: c, winapi, com-порт, модемы

Есть USB-модем, задача - отправить ему АТ-команду и получить ответ. Проще некуда.

Открываю таким образом:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM44", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
DCB dcb;
memset(&dcb, 0, sizeof(dcb));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

GetCommState(handle, &dcb);
dcb.BaudRate = 460800;
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
SetCommState(handle, &dcb);
```

Отправляю данные через WriteFile, а принимаю примерно так:

```
char buf[64];
size_t bufLen = sizeof(buf);
DWORD iSize = 0;
OVERLAPPED ovlp;
memset (&ovlp, 0, sizeof(ovlp));

char tmp = 0;
size_t i = 0;

while (i < (bufLen - 1))
{

    if (ReadFile(handle, &(tmp), 1, &iSize, &ovlp) == 0)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            return -1;
        while (GetOverlappedResult (handle, &ovlp, &iSize, 1) == 0) 
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE)
                return -1;
        if (iSize > 0)
            buf[i++] = tmp;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';

}
```

Собственно, общался таким образом с Arduino, данные принимались более-менее нормально. Однако при отправке команды "AT" на модем и последующем считывании ответа (делается это в двух потоках), получаю только то, что сам же и отправил, то есть ответа от модема никакого не приходит. Дебаггер показывает, что на этапе приема приложение встает на строке 17 в листинге приема, то есть функция GetOverlappedResult даже не завершается после приема двух символов, отправленных мной ("AT"), а просто зависает.
Тестил модем через Putty с теми же настройками - все ок.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Я подозреваю проблему с использованием overlapped. Попробуйте то же самое без них, для начала.

Comment: раз Вы получаете то что отправили значит у Вас включен режима эха. попробуйте его выключить, придет ли Вам то что необходимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена: необходимо отправлять символ перевода строки (`"AT\r\n"`).